# python api json childnode into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, child-nodes

I have a api json file with childnode. How do I unpack the childnode? Now I'm only getting everyting into one column see screenshot for code and illustration.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
response_info  = json.loads(resp)
pd.json_normalize(response_info['Holdings'])
```